# How to pass Class of Class in ArrayList from one Activity to Another Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to pass one object of `ArrayList<Links>` to Next Activity.

I have checked use of [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to achieve this but I have one another **Class object** of `Stream` class in `Links` class.

How can i pass this **Links** object to Next Activity

#### `Links` class:

```
public class Links implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private Streams streams;

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param streams the streams to set
     */
    public void setStreams(Streams streams) {
        this.streams = streams;
    }

    /**
     * @return the streams
     */
    public Streams getStreams() {
        return streams;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /**
         ** WHAT CAN I DO HERE...???
         **/
    }
}
```

#### `Stream` Class:

```
public class Streams {
    private String link;
    private String stream;

    /**
     * @param link the link to set
     */
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    /**
     * @return the link
     */
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    /**
     * @param stream the stream to set
     */
    public void setStream(String stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }
    /**
     * @return the stream
     */
    public String getStream() {
        return stream;
    }
}
```

I want to send ArrayList object to next activity. how can i?

#### Updated:

I got this in `Logcat:`

```
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gtu.gtupapers/com.gtu.gtupapers.StreamSelection}: java.lang.NullPointerException: expected receiver of type com.gtu.gtupapers.Links, but got null
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2129)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: expected receiver of type com.gtu.gtupapers.Links, but got null
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getField(Native Method)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:269)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2066)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2235)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1655)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1986)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1209)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:4477)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at com.gtu.gtupapers.StreamSelection.onCreate(StreamSelection.java:16)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
06-19 16:23:00.820: E/AndroidRuntime(21080):    ... 11 more
```

Your help would be appreciated...

Comment: Simply make `Streams` implement `Parcelable` as well and use `dest.writeParcelable(streams, 0)`

Comment: @MattiasBuelens This is far from enough.

Comment: @WonderCsabo Of course, you also need a `Parcelable.Creator` for both and actually read/write the other properties as well. But really, that's already explained in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Links` class:

```
public class Links implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private Streams streams;

    public Links(String name, Streams streams) {
        this.name = name;
        this.streams = streams;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param streams the streams to set
     */
    public void setStreams(Streams streams) {
        this.streams = streams;
    }

    /**
     * @return the streams
     */
    public Streams getStreams() {
        return streams;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeParcelable(streams, flags);
    }

    public static Parcelable.Creator<Links> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Links>() {

        @Override
        public Links createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            String name = source.readString();
            Streams streams = source.readParcelable(Streams.class.getClassLoader());
            return new Links(name, streams);
        }

        @Override
        public Links[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Links[size];
        }
    };
}
```

`Streams` class:

```
public class Streams implements Parcelable {
    private String link;
    private String stream;

    public Streams(String link, String stream) {
        this.link = link;
        this.stream = stream;
    }
    /**
     * @param link the link to set
     */
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    /**
     * @return the link
     */
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    /**
     * @param stream the stream to set
     */
    public void setStream(String stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }
    /**
     * @return the stream
     */
    public String getStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(link);
        dest.writeString(stream);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Streams> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Streams>() {

        @Override
        public Streams createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            String link = source.readString();
            String stream = source.readString();
            return new Streams(link, stream);
        }

        @Override
        public Streams[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Streams[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Then you can pass the list:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("links", yourList);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in `OtherActivity`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<Links> links = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("links");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have implemented like that but i got errors. See my updated question.

Comment: Be sure the fields are not `null` in the passed objects.

Comment: Accepted dear. posted mine answer also.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: What i have to change if i take `Stream[]` instead `Stream` in `Links` class?

Comment: @PratikButani can you explain what do you want to do?

Comment: I want `Stream[]` instead `Stream` so What i have to Change in Parcelable's Methods.

Comment: You have to use `readParcelableArray()` and writeParcelableArray() methods for that.

Answer (score 2):

Make both classes Parcelable using the Parcelabler at http://www.parcelabler.com/

Comment: Thanks. This link is helpful to create `parcelable` class.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [WonderCsabo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/747412/wondercsabo) for creating both class [Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304513/1318946) but i have created using this [link](http://www.parcelabler.com/) So also Thanks to [Zhuinden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/zhuinden) for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24304751/1318946).

I am posting full answer which will be helpful to others also.

#### *Links* class:

```
public class Links implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private Streams streams;

    public Links() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stud
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param streams the streams to set
     */
    public void setStreams(Streams streams) {
    this.streams = streams;
    }

    /**
     * @return the streams
     */
    public Streams getStreams() {
    return streams;
    }

    protected Links(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    streams = (Streams) in.readValue(Streams.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeValue(streams);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Links> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Links>() {
    @Override
    public Links createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Links(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Links[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Links[size];
    }
    };
}
```

#### *Streams* class:

```
public class Streams implements Parcelable {

    private String link;
    private String stream;

    Streams() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected Streams(Parcel in) {
    link = in.readString();
    stream = in.readString();
    }

    /**
     * @param link the link to set
     */
    public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
    }
    /**
     * @return the link
     */
    public String getLink() {
    return link;
    }
    /**
     * @param stream the stream to set
     */
    public void setStream(String stream) {
    this.stream = stream;
    }
    /**
     * @return the stream
     */
    public String getStream() {
    return stream;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(link);
    dest.writeString(stream);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Streams> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Streams>() {
    @Override
    public Streams createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Streams(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Streams[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Streams[size];
    }
    };
}
```

then Finally send to next `Activity` using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StreamSelection.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", arrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

And Receiving:

```
ArrayList<Links> links =  getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
int pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
Log.d("TAG", "Links: " + links.get(pos).getName());
```

Thanks for help.