# intent.getExtra() returns null object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to pass class object between two activities in my android application, but I always get null on the other activity.

here is my code :

To pass data :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    try {
        Products mCurrentProduct = (Products) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
        Intent mProductDescription = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity_ProductDescription.class);
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putParcelable(GlobalStrings.EXTRA_MESSAGE_DATA, mCurrentProduct);
        mProductDescription.putExtras(mBundle);

        if (mProductDescription != null)
            startActivity(mProductDescription);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Selection erro :",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

To get data :

```
  Intent mIntent =  getIntent();
        Bundle mBundleData = mIntent.getExtras();
        Products mCurrentProduct = (Products) mBundleData.getParcelable(EXTRA_MESSAGE_DATA);
        Products p = (Products) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_DATA); // p is always null here.
```

my parcable class:

```
    public class Products implements Parcelable {

    public String productName;
    public double productPrice;
    public String productSize;
    public String productWeight;
    public String productDescription;
    public String brandName;
    public byte[] productImage;
    public String seller;

    public Products(String productName, double productPrice, String productSize, String productWeight,
                    String productDescription, String brandName, byte[] productImage, String seller) {

        this.productName = productName;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.productSize = productSize;
        this.productWeight = productWeight;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.productImage = productImage;
        this.seller = seller;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public double getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductSize() {
        return productSize;
    }

    public String getProductWeight() {
        return productWeight;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    public byte[] getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public String getSeller() {
        return seller;
    }

    private Products(Parcel p) {
        this.productName = p.readString();
        this.productPrice = p.readDouble();
        this.productSize = p.readString();
        this.productWeight = p.readString();
        this.productDescription = p.readString();
        this.brandName = p.readString();
        p.readByteArray(productImage);
        this.seller = p.readString();
    }
    public static final Creator<Products> CREATOR = new Creator<Products>() {

        @Override
        public Products createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new Products(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public Products[] newArray(int i) {
            return new Products[i];
        }
    };
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(productName);
        parcel.writeString(productSize);
        parcel.writeString(productWeight);
        parcel.writeString(productDescription);
        parcel.writeString(brandName);
        parcel.writeString(seller);
        parcel.writeByteArray(productImage);
        parcel.writeDouble(productPrice);

    }
}
```

code to prepare adapter for listview:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("GetProductsResult");

for ( int i=0; i < jsonArray.length();i++  )
{
JSONObject jsonObjectArr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

productsList.add(new Products(
        jsonObjectArr.getString("ProductName"),
        jsonObjectArr.getDouble("ProductPrice"),
        jsonObjectArr.getString("ProductSize"),
        jsonObjectArr.getString("ProductWeight"),
        jsonObjectArr.getString("ProductDescription"),
        jsonObjectArr.getString("BrandName"),
        jsonObjectArr.getString("ProductImage").getBytes(),
        jsonObjectArr.getString("Seller")));

}

ArrayAdapter<Products> adapter = new ProductListItemAdapters(this,R.layout.list_products,productsList);
mListViewProductList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProductList);
mListViewProductList.setAdapter(adapter);
mListViewProductList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Adapter Class

```
public class ProductListItemAdapters extends ArrayAdapter<Products> {

Context mainContext;
List<Products> productList;
int resourceId;

public ProductListItemAdapters(Context context, int resource, List<Products> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mainContext = context;
    productList = objects;
    resourceId = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View itemView = convertView;
        try {

            if (itemView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mainContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_products, parent, false);
            }

            Products prod = productList.get(position);

            TextView txtViewSeller = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_productSeller);
            txtViewSeller.setText(prod.getSeller());

            TextView txtViewBrand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_productBrand);
            txtViewBrand.setText(prod.getBrandName());

            TextView txtViewProduct = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_productName);
            txtViewProduct.setText(prod.getProductName());

            TextView txtViewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_productDesc);
            txtViewDesc.setText(prod.getProductDescription());

            TextView txtViewPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_productPrice);
            txtViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(prod.getProductPrice()));

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("err", e.toString() );}

    return itemView;
}
```

}

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Share your adapter code here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24305177/1318946

Comment: use Serializable instead.. its an easy approach..

Comment: @PankajKumar edited the post with adapter code.

Comment: I was asking about `ProductListItemAdapters` code. Did you get the value for `mCurrentProduct` on itemClick method?? Put log there any say me the result.

Comment: @PankajKumar yes I do get Product object with values in mCurrentProduct on itemClick method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Android recomendation I will always suggest to use  `Parcelable`.

`Parcel` and `Parcelable` are quick, but its documentation says you must not use it for general-purpose serialization to storage, since the implementation varies with different versions of Android (i.e. an OS update could break an app which relied on it)

Simple implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. it is simple and easy to use.
something like:

```
public class Products implements Serializable{
   //write all your getter/setter methods here
}
```

And send the object in simple `putExtra()` method of your intent and get it as

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the answering your actual question, but there is mistake you have did. The sequence of fields you are writting to parcel must be same while reading.

like

```
// You followed this sequesnce for writting
parcel.writeString(productName);
    parcel.writeString(productSize);
    parcel.writeString(productWeight);
    parcel.writeString(productDescription);
    parcel.writeString(brandName);
    parcel.writeString(seller);
    parcel.writeByteArray(productImage);
    parcel.writeDouble(productPrice);
```

But while reading

```
this.productName = p.readString();
    this.productPrice = p.readDouble();
    this.productSize = p.readString();
```

Does not match the sequence.

Comment: Pankaj is correct.. this is super important. parcelables MUST be written in the exact order they will be read..

Comment: `this.productName = p.readString();
 this.productSize = p.readString();
 this.productWeight = p.readString();
 this.productDescription = p.readString();
 this.brandName = p.readString();
 this.seller = p.readString();
 p.readByteArray(productImage);
 this.productPrice = p.readDouble();`

I changed the sequence like this now, but still no luck .

Comment: Yes Now this is correct. If you problem did not solved, share your adapter code.